# Twitter API reply (in_reply_to_status_id) not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am using the Twit library to build a Twitter bot in node.js. However, when I want to post a reply to a tweet, it appears, but not in the reply stream.

My code:

```
twitter.post('statuses/update', { in_reply_to_status_id: data.statuses[0].user.id, status: '@' + data.statuses[0].user.screen_name + ' -some message-' }, function (err, data, res) {});
```

Where `data` is a tweet object I got from a search request.

Any help on this?

Comment: What stream does it appear on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value for the parameter `in_reply_to_status_id` must be a Tweet ID to preserve the conversation. You passed here a user ID instead of a Tweet ID.

Also, when working with JavaScript in particular, please make sure you use the stringified IDs `id_str` instead of `id` to avoid any integer overflow issues.

As a result, below is the updated line of code with the stringified Tweet ID:

```
twitter.post('statuses/update', { in_reply_to_status_id: data.statuses[0].id_str, status: '@' + data.statuses[0].user.screen_name + ' -some message-' }, function (err, data, res) {});
```

Comment: `id_str` rather than `id` was the key to this issue for me. So much time wasted on that! Nice one.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue with replying to a particular tweet. Here are sample parameters which resolved my issue:

```
var username = user.screen_name;
var params= {
  in_reply_to_status_id:'715236671738908672',
  status:`@${username} ${message}`
}
```

Where the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter contains a value of `id_str` instead of `id` of a particular tweet and the `status` parameter contains the value of `"@"+user.screen_name+"message"`.

Comment: As of 2019, @user.screen_name was not needed, if it was threaded on its own post.

Answer (score 5):

you should add @username of the replied tweet in the status of the tweet.

Note: This (**in_reply_to_status_id**) parameter will be ignored unless the author of the Tweet this parameter references is mentioned within the status text. Therefore, you must include **@username**, where username is the author of the referenced Tweet, within the update.