# Send a reply to a tweet sends a tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to send a reply to a tweet by giving the tweet_id, but instead of sending a reply, it sends a tweet. I feel like the tweet_id isn't user in the function.

Here's the code I have:

```js
function(properties, context) {
    var Twitter = require('twitter');

    var client = new Twitter({
      consumer_key: context.keys["ConsumerKey"],
      consumer_secret: context.keys["ConsumerSecret"],
      access_token_key: context.keys["AccessTokenKey"],
      access_token_secret: context.keys["AccessTokenSecret"]
    });

    let result = context.async(async callback => {
      // Reply to the tweet
      client.post(
        'statuses/update',
        {
          status: properties.message,
          in_reply_to_status_id: properties.tweet_id
        },
        function(error, tweet, response) {
          if (error) {
            callback(error[0].code + ':' + error[0].message);
          } else {
            callback(null, 'OK');
          }
        }
      );
    });

    return { tweet_result: result };
}
```

Comment: Replies *are* tweets.

Comment: Yeah, but, in this case I want them to be sent as replies to a main tweet, but instead, they are sent as just main tweets. I don't know if it's clear.

Comment: This question is similar: [Twitter API reply (in\_reply\_to\_status\_id) not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764886/twitter-api-reply-in-reply-to-status-id-not-working-properly)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will answer to both here. So similarity with another question, indeed, I already saw it, and I updated my code to use id_str. For the attempt, I have a form with a tweet_id and a message, so I tried to add @handle of creator of the tweet_id, but still the result was a tweet, instead of a reply. It's as if the tweet id isn't taken in account...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the description of the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter from the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) for the `statuses/update` API:

> The ID of an existing status that the update is in reply to. Note: This parameter will be ignored unless the author of the Tweet this parameter references is mentioned within the status text. Therefore, you must include @username , where username is the author of the referenced Tweet, within the update.

If `properties.message` doesn't "at" the person you want to reply to, it won't be sent as a reply.

Comment: I just tried it in many way, but it still sends a main tweet instead of a reply :/

Comment: Please include your attempt as part of the question to show what didn't work.

Comment: This is indeed the solution, I had a little problem processing the @username which kept it from working, but now it works fine. Thank you!